# Is it possible to have multiple Asset folders and if so how can you use them?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've got different PDF files that I would like to view depending on item I choose and I was hoping to be able to separate the files by folders. That way I could iterate through the folder. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to have multiple asset files just put multiple folder in asset file instead.

**more clarification**

```
asset--
       |--font.ttf
       |basketball--
                    |--font2.ttf
                    |--font3.ttf
       |football  --
                    |--font4.ttf
```

Comment: I saw how to add the folders in the Assets folder. How do you access the folder?

Comment: asset/folder/font.ttf

Comment: So if I had a folder called basketball and several files in it what code can I use to call my files. The only way that I know to get assets is getAssets() method.

Comment: when you try to use asset file it by default address to it's root like font.ttf but actually it's asset/font.ttf when you have a folder like basketball/font.ttf actually it's asset/basketball/font.ttf.